# how this function works

Tags: javascript, jquery

in javaScript : navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccessLocation, onErrorLocation);

```
In the above code Success Location working fine when i click share location button popup (would you like to share your location) in browser. but i want  Error Location. it will not working when i clicked Not Now in browser.
```

Comment: at least when errorLocation function is called..pls tell me any one..

Answer (score 0):

Use this snippet and check your developer tools console to see errors:

```
var options = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  maximumAge: 0
};

function success(pos) {
  var crd = pos.coords;

  console.log('Your current position is:');
  console.log('Latitude : ' + crd.latitude);
  console.log('Longitude: ' + crd.longitude);
  console.log('More or less ' + crd.accuracy + ' meters.');
};

function error(err) {
  console.warn('ERROR(' + err.code + '): ' + err.message);
};

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error, options);
```

Comment: What do you mean nothing happens? there must be another error blocking the function from firing I guess... try using alert('test1') alert('test2') in different parts of the function code to see which is running and which is not.

Comment: alert(" test1") coming fine.. when click share location popup in browser. but when i click not now popup in browser nothing happen means alert("tast2) not coming.. i put test2 in error function ..

Comment: There you go, you have to find out why alert('test2') is not firing, try adding more alerts. In addition, I strongly recommend you validate your HTML using http://validator.w3.org/ to see you don't have any errors.